# How to get woocommerce reviews by product_id?

Tags: angular, woocommerce, product, rating, review

How will integrate the woocomerce api product review and star rating?
When i run the code, it does not show on html it says ERROR TypeError: a.productReviews is undefined.

api.service.ts:

```
getProductReviews(pid: any) {
const url = `${this.apiUrl}/ecom/wp-json/wc/v3/products/reviews/${pid}?consumer_key=${
  this.consumerKey
}&consumer_secret=${this.consumerSecret}`;
console.log(url);
return this.http.get(url);
```

}

in my ts file:

```
 getProductReviews() {
this.apiService.getProductReviews(this.id).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.productReviews = data;
    console.log(this.productReviews);
  },
  (error) => {
    this.errorMessage = error.error.message;
    console.log(error.error.message, 'error');

  }
);
```

}

---

in my html:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <div class="">
        <h4 [innerHTML]="productReviews.review"></h4>
        
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what's not working. ?

Comment: hi @MatthieuRiegler, i corrected the codes above, when i run it, the product reviews doesn't show.